# Understanding OAuth2 flow

Tags: rest, oauth

I'm developing an Android app that consumes a REST service that uses OAuth protocol. In the first activity, app shows a login screen. This is the flow:

1) User puts her username and password.

2) App makes a request to REST service, providing username and password.

3) REST service check the credentials and if are correct, ask for an `access_token` to my OAuth2 provider server.

4) REST service answers to the app providing the `access_token` and the `refresh_token`

5) In the next requests to the REST server (to get data like people, articles...) app will provide the `access_token` and the `refresh_token`.

6) When REST service process a request, will validate the `access_token` (using an token info endpoint of my OAuth server).

7) If the access_token is correct and has not expired, REST service will return the data that the app were asking for.

When REST service detects that `access_token` has expired, asks for another with using the `refresh_roken`.

Now, my questions:

When REST service retrieve a new `access_token` after the old one expires, has the REST service send it to the app in that response?

If so, has the app check, in each request/response, if new a new `access_token` has been sent from the REST service?

I don't know if I'm in the right way, I'm trying to understand the flow.

Thanks.

Comment: firstly, the app would not send the username/password to the REST API but rather to the Authorization Server

Comment: And what should Authorization Server answers with? The tokens?

Comment: Yes, that is the primary function of an Authorization Server

Comment: Nice. Then, in each request to the REST API, the app must provide the access_token and refresh_token?

Comment: no, the `access_token` is only ever presented to the REST API to get access to the protected resource, the `refresh_token` is only ever presented to the Authorization Server to get a new access token when the old one has expired

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming there's no browser involved and the app (aka. Client) uses what is called the Resource Owner Password Credentials grant, the flow is:

1. the User (aka. Resource Owner) provides his/her username and password to the Client
2. the Client makes a Token Request to the Authorization Server, providing username and password
3. the Authorization Server checks the credentials and if they are correct, it provides an access token and optionally a refresh token to the Client in the response
4. in the requests to the REST server (to get data like people, articles...) the Client will provide the access token
5. when the REST service process a request, it will validate the access token calling the token validation endpoint of the Authorization Server or by validating the token locally (e.g. if the access token is a JWT).
6. if the access token is correct, has not expired and has the right permissions (aka. "scopes"), the REST service will return the data that the Client was asking for
7. when the Client detects that access_token has expired (e.g. because the REST server returns an error), it asks the Authorization Server for another access token using the refresh token using the so-called Refresh Token grant/flow

Comment: Thanks. Perfectly explained. One last question, in this case the `grant_type` is "password", isnt it?

Comment: yes, the spec-defined `grant_type` value for the Resource Owner Credentials grant is `password`

Comment: @HansZ., Spring Security OAuth doc says `Authorization` endpoint should be the only accessible for an authenticated users. How does `Client` allowed to make the Authorization Request, if he isn't authenticated yet?

Comment: the Resource Owner Password Credentials flow is executed against the Token endpoint of the Authorization Server, not the Authorization endpoint

Comment: @HansZ., `the Client makes an Authorization Request to the Authorization Server` then does it mean "Authorization Request" is used in the `Token` endpoint context and not the `Authorization` one? Shouldn't `Authorization` endpoint be used in the case you've described at all?

Answer (score 1):

OAuth 2.0 flows:

1. An application registers with the auth provider e.g. Facebook, Google, etc with app name, website and callback/postback URL
2. The application receives the client id and secret from the auth provider
3. The application user accesses the auth provider for authentication and user approves the resource permissions
4. The auth provider returns the auth token with respect to the user permissions to the application
5. The application accesses the resource provider using the auth tokens
6. The resource provider returns the protected resources after validating the auth tokens to the application

Do comment if you need more understanding!

Comment: I want to know does creating a google calendar event from the mobile side need any communication with a backend? for example, an `/oauth2callback` endpoint or a generator google auth url endpoint in the backend? or it can be done from mobile side standalone using client_id, client_secret, and google calendar scopes directly?